# Terminator 'hunter killers' phrase vs 2018 movie titled "Hunter Killer"

Tags: the-terminator, hunter-killer

In *The Terminator* (1984), Kyle Reese uses the expression "HK", which he explains stands for "hunter killers".  Fast forward to 2018, when the action movie *Hunter Killer* is released.  Wikipedia lists Director James Cameron and Producer Gale Anne Hurd as the writers of *Terminator*.  Also, according to Wikipedia, neither had any hand in *Hunter Killer*.  If this is correct:

Does the fact that the 2018 movie is titled using a phrase from *The Terminator* represent: a) an obvious rip-off, b) sort of a rip-off, or c) not a rip-off at all, and possibly a coincidence?

Comment: It's just a coincidence, "Hunter-Killer" isn't unique to terminator or the 2018 movie title and I doubt was created for Terminator either.

Comment: Downvoted because, based on iandotkelly's answer, you clearly didn't do any research into Hunter Killer beyond the name. A five-second Google search would have made it obvious it has nothing to do with Terminator whatsoever.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, "hunter killer" is also the name given to the little drone robot that tries to assassinate Paul Atreides near the beginning of the novel *Dune.*

Answer (score 7):

Hunter Killer is an accepted name for [Attack Submarines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_submarine), the purpose of which are to track (and potentially) sink other ships and submarines, as opposed to missile submarines which have a primary purpose targeting weapons such as nuclear missiles at land.

[Hunter Killer](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1846589/) is a movie about submarines. If anything Terminator is borrowing and repurposing the terminology.